# Need of normalizing data

Tags: machine-learning

I tried the code found on this blog post:

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/hands-on-with-deep-learning-solution-for-age-detection-practice-problem/

The article says that "*Normalizing the images will make our train faster*."

```
train_x = train_x / 255.
test_x = test_x / 255.
```

I did not understand the need for normalization here. And what is the basis of selecting the number 255, or is it a random number?

Comment: Please describe the problem in your own words (and some code) and explain what are you trying to normalize

Comment: After reading the problem, I'm assuming this "article" is talking about some kind of image processing using a 255 bit color pictures.

I guess they normalize with the max size of the color, though I'm not sure this is the best way to normalize the data.

Comment: The need for normalization is a general need of neural networks. It helps them converge to a solution faster.

Comment: X_test.max() returns 255. But as you have suggested, this may not be the right way to normalize.

Comment: I guess MinMaxScaler or StandardScaler are the standard scaling techniques. Dividing by max value is easy. But not sure if the right approach.

Comment: I would take standard deviation normalization. For each column, subtract column average and divide by the column standard deviation (x-mean(x)) / variation(x). You can test both and tell us whats better in terms of speed and accuracy.

Comment: I cant tell if its a good solution. "subtract minimum, divide by range" is good if you have for example values between 50 to 70. so in case of 60 you do (60-50)/20 This will normalize the data to be between 0 to 1. this is the same approach your article suggest. It might work. or not. YOU need to TEST both approaches and get a conclusion.

Comment: StandardScaler gives you average of 0 with std of 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did not understand the need for normalization here

As long as you work with Neural-Networks, you have, the most of the time, to apply techniques of '[normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics))' or 'standardization' to your data so that it can fit the model.

note: this is a "need" imposed by the [activation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function) of the neurons in the NN.

> *Normalizing the images will make our train faster.*

This is **wrong**!  Normalization has nothing to do with the training speed, normalized data permit to the model to learn the importance and the correlation between the features. The most of the time a "non-normalized" data don't permit a correct approximation of the input, resulting in strange results.

> And what is the basis of selecting the number 255, or is it a random number?

In this case, has been selected 255, cause in an [RGB](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB) image, the three levels of color are represented in a range between 0 and 255, where 0 is "Absence of color" and 255("Presence of color"); note: in gray-scale: 0 is "black" and 255 is "white".

---

### Math references:

**Normalization**:

[image]

where *a* and *b* indicates the *range*, in this case: 0 - 255;

**Standardization**:

[image]